# Trace Operation in Python not Forming Correct Array Shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, vtk

I'm looking to find the trace of matrices (using Numpy) in a function I have defined in Python. The input parameters `tensor` and `tensor_transpose` are both matrices of size (N,2,2) and are extracted from a VTK file (N is a rather large number and varies depending on the file). So both `A` and `B` are arrays of (N,2,2). By taking the trace of each array (sum of the diagonal terms), a single value for each array should be returned. So `np.trace(A)**3)-(np.trace(B)**3` should be a single numerical value, with the array being of shape (N,1). My output though does not show this, with the returned shape being `(2,)`.

Can anyone explain why? Is it an issue with the `trace` function and is there a solution?

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array(0.5*(tensor-tensor_transpose))
B=np.array(0.5*(tensor+tensor_transpose))
C=np.array(0.5*((np.trace(A)**3)-(np.trace(B)**3)))

print(A.shape)
print(B.shape)
print(C.shape)

#Output
#(60600, 2, 2)
#(60600, 2, 2)
#(2,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to specify the axes:

```py
np.trace(A, axis1=1, axis2=2)
```